# Forwarding ipv6 link local destined traffic not working

Tags: linux, linux-networking, ipv6, linux-kernel

Setup:

> VM (eth0) -> hostveth -> ContainerVeth

eth0 and hostveth are in VM network namespace while containerveth is in different namespace

sysctl ipv6 forwarding and iptables FORWARD chain are allowed. Checked filter table and no rule to block link local ipv6.

Request coming from outside of VM to Linux pod (container). Pod receives a request from linklocal ip and it responded back to the request with linklocal ip as dst ip . The response reached VM (took tcpdump on hostveth) but its not getting forwarded to VM eth0. This forwarding worked for other ipv6 destined addresses. Please let me know if i'm missing something. Happy to provide more details. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: How did you alter the traffic?

Comment: IP routing. Added ipv6 default gw to route from veth to eth0

Comment: Packets with Link local addresses cannot be forwarded between interfaces/links. It’s explicitly not allowed by the standard. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291.html#section-2.5.6

Comment: Thanks sander. is there any workaround/way we can achieve this?